# phpBB 3: finding additional user field in the underlying database

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I use phpBB 3.0.7-PL1 (upgrading soon) with CentOS 5.5 and PostgreSQL 8.4.6 and have the following additional question shown to new users on their registration to prevent SPAM:

```
What is your gender please? Answers: Robot/Man/Woman
```

I have found the corresponding entries in the database:

```
pref=> select * from phpbb_profile_lang;
 field_id | lang_id | lang_name |        lang_explain         | lang_default_value
----------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------------
        5 |       2 | Sex       | Please specify your gender  |
(1 row)

pref=> select * from phpbb_profile_fields_lang;
 field_id | lang_id | option_id | field_type | lang_value
----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------
        5 |       2 |         0 |          5 | Robot
        5 |       2 |         1 |          5 | Man
        5 |       2 |         2 |          5 | Woman
(3 rows)
```

My problem is: I would like to find out now, which user is **Man** and which user is **Woman** (I need it for the game integrated in my forum in Russian language, so that I can refer to the players correctly).

But I can't find, where these values are stored, in which "phpbb_xxxx" table and field. Does anybody please know?

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found it by changing a user's gender and diffing the database dumps - it is in the table **phpbb_profile_fields_data**

And I've fetched that value in index.php with:

```
$sql = 'SELECT pf_sex FROM ' . 
  PROFILE_FIELDS_DATA_TABLE . 
  ' WHERE user_id=' . $user->data['user_id'];
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
if ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
        $pf_sex = $row['pf_sex'];
$db->sql_freeresult($result);
```